# Is $f$ continuous? Is $f^{-1}$ continuous?

Tags: general-topology

Define the function $f: \mathbb{N} \to Y$ where $\mathbb{N}$ has the discrete topology, and $Y$ is the set $\{0, \frac{1}{n} | n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ with the relative topology from $\mathbb{R}$:

$$
f(n)=
\begin{cases}
0 & n=1\\
\frac{1}{n - 1} & n>1\\
\end{cases}
$$

Is $f$ continuous? Is $f^{-1}$ continuous?

My attempt:

$f$ is continuous since $\mathbb{N}$ has the discrete topology.

$f^{-1}$ is not continuous. If we consider the open set $U = \{1, 3, 5, 7, ... \}$, then $f(U) = \{0, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{6}, ... \}$. But $f(U)$ is not an open set in $Y$ since any open set containing $0$ must also contain elements of the form $\frac{1}{n}$ where $n$ is odd.

Is my reasoning right?

Comment: Or simplre: $f(\{1\})=\{0\}$ is not open:

Comment: Your proof looks fine to me.

Comment: Thanks @HagenvonEitzen, that's a very nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your right about $f$: any function on a discrete space is continuous. But more simply: $f^{-1}$ is not continuous as $f$ is not open: $f[\{1\}] = \{0\}$ and the latter is not open as any neighbourhood of $0$ also contains infinitely many points of the form  $\frac{1}{n}$.